# Minolta MD lenses to Canon 6D body

Tags: lens, adapter, canon-6d, minolta

Is it possible to use Minolta SR/MC/MD lenses on Canon 6D?

I understand that it is 2 different mount systems- so I will need some sort of adapter.
Also as I understand from wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_SR-mount and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) I will need an adapter which will compensate 0.5mm difference. In that case- how to find the right adapter?

Comment: What's your favourite camera store? Have you tried them? I just searched online and found adapters available for Minolta MD/MC/SR Lens to Canon EF-Mount. I note though that the adapters I found include a glass element to maintain infinity focus.

Comment: I'm using multiple stores, but mostly those are ebay, bfs.lv and masterfoto.lv. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong- but if adapter "maintains" infinte focus, then it is my way to go? (I got in to camera world just a few months ago, and I'm still very confused about all the stuff)

Comment: Each camera mount has a flange distance, the distance the mounting flange sits in front of the film/sensor.  If the flange distance of your camera is longer than the distance the lens is designed for, it is like focusing close where you move the lens away from the sensor.  The glass in the adapter is to compensate for this.  You can search this site or the internet for information on flange distances.

Comment: Why do you want to use Minolta lenses? They are difficult to adapt to the Canon EF mount. Nikon, Olympus, Pentax, etc are much easier to adapt because they can use a simple adapter without a corrective optical lens.

Comment: @MikeSowsun reason why I want to use Minolta lenses is that I have 50mm and 200mm lenses for my Minolta XG2, so I would like to reuse them on Canon (at least at the beginning)

Comment: Just to link this here for future searchers - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y